# AJAX Refresh Comments Link/Icon/Button

Tags: feature-request, comments

I think it would be useful to add a "Refresh comments" button or subtle link somewhere, for those times when you are going back-and-forth with the OP on the comments.  Otherwise I just keep refreshing the entire page and I have to continuously click the "Show rest of comments" link.

Comment: Why not just use chat? Or wave?